# Ubuntu on Nexus 7 vs. Ubuntu on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, galaxy-nexus

I can find already a lot of material about Ubuntu on Nexus 7. This is all very exciting and even the average user is able to install Ubuntu on a Nexus 7 and play around with it.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7

On the other side there were quite a good amount of presentations by Mark Shuttleworth of Ubuntu on Galaxy Nexus. Videos Presentation, CES, youtube, etc.

Ubuntu on Galaxy Nexus: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLtcj7FdIYA

I am wondering how this goes together. If there is already a working preview on Galaxy Nexus, why is this not already an active/public development platform for Ubuntu?

Comment: Look at the dates - Nexus 7 Ubuntu was announced *before* the Ubuntu for Phones announcement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The release of Ubuntu for Nexus 7 is an exercise in helping shape up the Ubuntu experience for tablets - the purpose of releasing it to the public is to allow developers, testers and users to get to grips with it and provide feedback.

The development of Ubuntu for mobiles (http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone) is one which aims to provide, in future an OS for mobile phones that could either be available as the default operating system on a phone the day you buy it, or as a replacement OS for phones that allows such functionality, like the Galaxy Nexus.

The Ubuntu Mobile OS is still heavily in development and isn't ready to be shown or distributed publicly but it's also not a full deployment of 'Ubuntu' (as we know it today) either.

Hope that helps.